# How to redirect from payment page to index page

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views

After payment, I have redirected it to the success page.

```
form action="success" method="POST"
```

Views tab

```
def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html')
```

Now I want the page to automatically redirect to the index/home page after a small delay.

How can that be achieved. Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return render(request, 'success.html')`, use `return redirect('index')` where index is name of the url of `index`. Make sure, in `urls.py` , there is a url for `index`, `path('index',views.index,name='index')`

Comment: First, I want to show the user that their payment is successful and then I want to redirect it to the index page. So I rendered it to the success page and then need a very small delay then redirect it to the index page. Is there any other way to achieve it and am I trying to do it incorrectly?

Comment: You could use `time.sleep`. First redirect to success page, then use `time.sleep(n)` where `n` is number of seconds. Then redirect to index page

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this by using `setTimeout` and `window.location.href` in javascript.

using `time.sleep` is another option here, but this will make the request stop for seconds, and this may raise request timeout.

success

```py
def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html')
```

success.html

```html
<script>
function redirect () {
        var x = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "{% url 'index' %}";
            window.clearTimeout(x);     // clear time out.
        }, 5000);
</script>
```